# How to check that my custom object is a junction object?

Tags: custom-object

I want to know that my custom object is junction object or not?
How to check with an example or scenario?
Give a scenario to check weather my junction object is doing properly or not.

Thanks 
Tanushree Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Junction object can have two master-detail relationShips you can easily find out the junction object.
Go to create > objects and check which object have 2 master objects.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply, if it has two Master-Details custom fields on it, then it is a junction object.

For example, if you wanted to relate Contacts to more than one Account, then you could create a Custom Object called Contact_to_Account__c. To make it a junction object, you would create a Master-Detail field on Contact_to_Account__c, related to Account; and another Master-Detail field on Contact_to_Account__c, related to Contact.

You can then add whatever additional information you might want to the junction object. For example Type__c: In the example above, Contact Bob might be related to ACME as with Type__c=Employee and WidgetCo with Type__c=Ex-employee.